# Can't databind an IEnumerable of DataRows? HttpException?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, ienumerable

I have a function that returns a DataTable that I can databind to a DropDownlist or Repeater just fine. However, if I databind an IEnumerable of the DataTable's DataRows, I get an HttpException: "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'some_column'".

```
repeater.DataSource = ThisReturnsDataTable();  // Works fine
repeater.DataSource = ThisReturnsDataTable.AsEnumerable();  // HttpException
```

Why is this?

I'm not looking for a solution to the problem, like for example:

```
repeater.DataSource = ThisReturnsDataTable().AsEnumerable().Select(
    x => new {some_column = x["some_column"]});
```

I simply want to know why the databinding with an IEnumerable of DataRows fails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a pretty good explanation [here](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/binding-to-lists-of-datarows.html), although his first solution to the problem, `AsDataView()`, doesn't seem to work/exist (in 3.5, at least). `CopyToDataTable()` works swimmingly, though.

> .Net DataTables can be very useful when writing data-driven
>   applications.  However, they have one limitation: There is no obvious
>   way to databind a grid (or other control) to an arbitrary list of
>   datarows from a table.  You can bind to an entire table directly by
>   setting a DataSource to the DataTable itself, and you can bind to a
>   subset of a table by creating a DataView with a filter.
>
> In general, you cannot bind to an IEnumerable (eg, a LINQ query);
>   the databinding infrastructure can only handle an IList (non-generic)
>   or an IListSource.  This is true for any kind of datasource. 
>   Therefore, to bind to any LINQ query, you need to call .ToList().  (Or
>   .ToArray())
>
> However, when binding to a DataTable, you  can’t even use a
>   List.  If you try, you’ll get four columns (RowError,
>   RowState, Table, and HasErrors) and no useful information.  This
>   happens because the List doesn’t tell the databinding
>   infrastructure about the special properties of the DataRows.  To
>   understand the problem, some background is necessary
>
> Databinding is controlled by the ListBindingHelper and TypeDescriptor
>   classes.  When you bind to a list, the
>   ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties method is called to get the
>   columns in the list.  If the list implements the ITypedList interface,
>   its GetItemProperties  method is called.  Otherwise, it will use
>   TypeDescriptor to get the properties of the first item in the list. 
>   (this uses reflection)
>
> The DataView class (which DataTable also binds through, using
>   IListSource) implements ITypedList and returns
>   DataColumnPropertyDescriptors that expose the columns in the table. 
>   This is why you can bind to a DataView or DataTable and see columns. 
>   However, when you bind to a List, there is no ITypedList that
>   can return the columns as properties.  It therefore falls back on
>   reflection and shows the physical properties of the DataRow class.
>
> To solve this issue, you need to wrap the list in a DataView so that
>   you can take advantage of its ITypedList implementation.  You can do
>   that using the AsDataView() method.  This method is only available on
>   the DataTable  and EnumerableRowCollection classes; it cannot be
>   called on an arbitrary LINQ query.  You can only get an
>   EnumerableRowCollection by calling special versions of the Cast,
>   OrderBy, Where, and Select methods from a DataTable.
>
> Therefore, you can databind to a simple LINQ query by calling
>   AsDataView() on the query.  To bind to a List, or to a more
>   complicated query, you can use an ugly hack:
>
> ```
>     List<DataRow> list = ...; 
>     grid.DataSource = datatable.AsEnumerable()
>                    .Where(list.Contains)
>                    .AsDataView();
> ```
>
> The  AsEnumerable() call is not needed for typed datasets.
>
> You can also call CopyToDataTable(), which will works [*sic*] on an arbitrary
>   IEnumerable.   However, it makes deep copies of the rows, so
>   it isn’t helpful if you want the user to update the data, or if you
>   want the user to see changes made (in code) to the original datarows.

From: http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/binding-to-lists-of-datarows.html

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe instead of doing the `.Where` clause, you should be able to do something like this:

```
DirectCast([datatable].AsEnumerable, EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow)).AsDataView()
```